# Unable to deploy ssd mobilenet v1 fpn on android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am using default ssd mobilenet v1 fpn model for object detection. It's running perfectly fine on my laptop but when I try to deploy the tflite file on android it gives me the error:

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
>           at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
>           at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
>           at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
>           at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at void org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (CameraActivity.java:95)
>           at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6984)
>           at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1235)
>           at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2783)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2909)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1606)
>           at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
>           at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6592)
>           at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
>           at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
>           at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:769)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-4snPFSE9sc16tBhI7Elm9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-4snPFSE9sc16tBhI7Elm9g==/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-4snPFSE9sc16tBhI7Elm9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
>           at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
>           at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
>           at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
>           at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at void org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (CameraActivity.java:95)
>           at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6984)
>           at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1235)
>           at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2783)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2909)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1606)
>           at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
>           at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6592)
>           at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
>           at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
>           at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:769)

A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25346 (inference)

But the app runs perfectly fine when i use ssd mobilenet v1

Could anyone guide me what to do? Any help would be greatful

Comment: It will be helpful if you could describe your problem a bit and post the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with deployment of ssd mobilenet v1 fpn on android.

Please refer to open issue in TF API (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5298)